# mocking AudioContext() in Jest

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, audiocontext

I have the following code inside a function in my project;

```
....
if (state.context == null) {
    return {
        ...state,
        context: new AudioContext()
    }
}
....
```

I'm trying to test this behaviour in Jest. However, Jest uses jsdom which doesn't support `AudioContext()`

In other tests I use;

```
.....
jest.spyOn(global.Math, 'random').mockReturnValue(0.3);
....
jest.spyOn(global.Math, 'random').mockRestore();
....
```

This doesn't work. When I call `spyOn(global /* or window */, 'AudioContext')` I get the error `Cannot spy the AudioContext property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`

I have also found this [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/standardized-audio-context-mock) which seems like it might work except that it requires you to use the mocked version of the function in the code, rather than overloading it as I have been doing with `random()`.

I would replace jsdom as my test environment, however, I haven't been able to find one that supports `AudioContext()`.

Is there a solution whereby I don't alter my source code? Passing into the function that calls `AudioContext()` a mocked or functional `AudioContext` at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of the library mentioned in the question. I think the following should work.

```
import { AudioContext } from 'standardized-audio-context-mock';

global.AudioContext = AudioContext;
```

However, I'm not a Jest user myself. Please let me know if it doesn't work and feel free to [open an issue](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/standardized-audio-context-mock/issues/new) for any bug you encounter.

Comment: how do i reset it?

Comment: Do you mean how you remove it again from the global object? I would expect `delete global.AudioContext` to work.

Comment: `global.AudioContext = AudioContext;` and `delete global.AudioContext` generate typescript errors.

Comment: The `delete` error was happening because `global.AudioContext` was being set to `undefined` to resolve this, I saved a reference to the function and restored it after I was done with that test.